# Blocking websites from DNS Level

Tags: windows, server

Is it possible to block website from DNS Level. Is it possible to create DNS server in windows server 2012?

Comment: You can't "block" a website, but if your dns does not return an address, then it's not possible to reach it -- and of course you can do that on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it pre-DNS pevel. Prior to DNS lookup, windows will check the hosts file for IP to domain mapping. You can set facebook.com to 192.168.1.1 and it will use that ip for facebook rather than looking it up in DNS, and thus blocking it. This would require modifying the host file on every machine you want to sensor though. Its a file in the system32 folder.

Comment: I know how to block it from adding websites in host file "system32/drivers/etc/host". but i need to create a new dns server like norton connect safe and post all unwanted sites in DNS.